# (C to MIPS)I dont know why I cant printf all of the output like C code do

Tags: c, mips

I had tried my best to turn the C code to mips code.
I cant find why I cant printf all of the output like C code do.
I think problem is about $ra, but I cant fix it.
I need help.
thanks for the nice guy like you.

I need output like this

1 2 3

1 2 4

1 2 5

1 3 4

1 3 5

1 4 5 *

2 3 4

2 3 5

2 4 5

3 4 5

but MIPS code will exit at *.

C

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int cl[3];
static int n=5;
static int k=3;
void dfs(int cur, int s ){
    int i;
    if (cur==k) {
        for (i=0; i<k; i++){
            printf("%d ",cl[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else{
        int p=n-k+cur+1;
        for (i=s; i<=p; i++){
            cl[cur]=i;
            dfs(cur+1,i+1);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
            dfs(0,1);

}
```

ASM

```
.data
cl: .word 0,0,0 #cl[3]
n: .word 5  #n=5
k: .word 3  #k=3
space:  .asciiz  " "
enter:  .asciiz "\n"
.text
main:   li  $s0, 0  #cur = 0
    li  $s1, 1  #s = 1
    jal dfs
    j   exit


dfs:    addi    $sp, $sp, -12
    sw  $ra, 0($sp)
    li  $t3, 0  #i=0
    lw  $t0, k  #k=3
if: bne $s0, $t0, else  #if(cur==k)
    la  $t0, cl     #get address of cl[i]
loop:   
    lw  $a0, ($t0)  #printf
    li  $v0, 1
    syscall
    la      $a0, space       # load address of spacer for syscall
        li      $v0, 4           # specify Print String service
        syscall 
    addi    $t3, $t3, 1 # i++
    addi    $t0, $t0, 4 # cl[i++]
    lw  $t1, k
    blt $t3, $t1,loop   #i<k 

    la      $a0, enter          # load address of enter for syscall
        li      $v0, 4              # specify Print String service
        syscall

    j   done

else:   lw  $s2, n      # n
    lw  $t0, k      # k
    sub $s2, $s2, $t0   #n-=k
    add $s2, $s2, $s0   #+=cur
    addi    $s2, $s2, 1 # +=1
    move    $t0, $s1    #i=s

loop2:  la  $t1, cl     #load address from cl
    sll $t2, $s0, 2 #t2=cur*4
    add $t1, $t1, $t2   #t1=*cl+cur*4
    sw  $t0, ($t1)  #cl[cur]=i

    addi    $s0, $s0, 1 #cur++
    addi    $s1, $t0, 1 #s=i+1
    sw  $t0, 4($sp)
    sw  $s2, 8($sp)
    jal dfs
    addi    $s0, $s0, -1    
    addi    $s1, $s1, -1    
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1
    ble $t0, $s2, loop2 #i<=s2 


done:   
    addi    $sp, $sp, 12
    lw  $ra, 0($sp)
    lw  $t0, 4($sp)
    lw  $s2, 8($sp)
    jr  $ra     #return void
exit:
```

Comment: That google link is to a .rar file? Is it a virus or a malware? Please do not post links to external site - post all information, including at best compilable [MCVE] of your program with the problem you are having, in your question as plain text formatted using markdown. `why I cant printf all of the answer` what answer? Answer to which question?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The code has to be in the question itself rather than in a Google Drive link. See [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing the stack pointer — popping it — too early in the function epilogue.  To reverse the prologue we change the sign of the immediate in adding to the stack pointer ***and move it to the end*** and otherwise change `sw`'s to `lw`'s.

```
done:   
    addi    $sp, $sp, 12          <--- this is too early
    lw  $ra, 0($sp)
    lw  $t0, 4($sp)
    lw  $s2, 8($sp)
                                  <--- it belongs here
   jr  $ra     #return void
```